# Maven - Test Failure

Tags: maven, jboss

When i do Maven Install i got that test error:
"Please refer to /home/fusew/workspace/homeloan/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results."

My pom.xml:
http://pastebin.com/REH0wND5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
maven clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `mvn install` command it will run all the life cycle phases up to and including `install`. This means Maven will run both the `test` and `report` phases by running any test code you have in `src/test/java` and creating files with the output of the test code. By default Maven uses its own plugin, Surefire, to run JUnit tests and reports the results of those tests using the Surefire-report plugin.

When there are test failures the surefire-report plugin will create a report stored in `${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports`. You are seeing the default message stating there were tests with failures and the results of those tests are in `/home/fusew/workspace/homeloan/target/surefire-reports`.